# How to Filter an NSMutableArray of Dictionaries?

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an mutable array which consists dictionaries of contacts

```
[
{
"name":""
"Email":""
type:"A"
},
"name":""
"Email":""
type:"B"
}
"name":""
"Email":""
type:"C"
}........100 contacts
]
```

i want to filter them by type A,B or C that is taken care by a segmented switch.My question how to use predicate in order to filter this type of case.

Here is my implementation of filtering

```
-(NSArray *)filtercontcts:(NSString *)filterParameter
{
    NSArray *filterContacts = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type ==  %@)",filterParameter];

    filterContacts= [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return filterContacts;

}
```

Help is Much Appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to create the predicate is without the closing bracket like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type ==  %@", filterParameter];
```

You are also leaking memory because you allocate `filterContacts` but then lose the reference to it when you overwrite the pointer with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, simply remove the `[[NSArray alloc]init];` to get rid of the leak.

Comment: arc does not take care of it??

Comment: @DheerajKaveti, In ARC, you can just write `NSArray *filterContacts;` The other portion is not needed. It is similar to `NSArray *filterContacts = [[NSArray alloc]init]; [filterContacts release]; filterContacts= [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`
 in non-arc, which may not leak anything but clearly is not needed.

Comment: how can you filter when you want more they to keys from each dictionary? lets say type and name and where the dictionary has 10 key value

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
NSArray *filterContacts = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category type[cd] %@,filterParameter];
filterContacts=[contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]mutableCopy];
```